# numpy array point in time present value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, finance

I have a numpy array of future cash flows and a discount rate of 0.01. I want to calculate the present value of future cash flows at each point in time. For example, if I want to calculate the present value at t=0, I would do:

```
cash_flow = np.array([3, 4, 5, 3, 5])
pv_0 = sum(cf/((1+0.01)**i) for i,cf in emunerate(cash_flow, start=1))
```

So at t = 1, I would do the same thing, except moving everything one period forward:

```
cash_flow_1 = np.array([4, 5, 3, 5])
pv_1 = sum(cf/((1+0.01)**i) for i,cf in emunerate(cash_flow_1, start=1))
```

I want the final result to be a numpy array as the original cash_flow array. Is there a smarter way to do that than writing a for loop over each element?

Edit:
Inspired by the conversation below, I have an "array" method (which is just my way of saying no loop...):

```
discount_array = np.geomspace((1/1.01)**5, 1/1.01, 5)
(np.cumsum(cash_flow[::-1]*discount_array)*np.geomspace((1.01)**4, 1, 5))[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
def cf_calc(arr):
    return sum(cf/((1+0.01)**i) for i,cf in enumerate(arr, start=1))

cfs_array = np.array([])   
for p in range(len(cash_flow)):
    cfs_array = np.append(cfs_array, cf_calc(cash_flow[p:]))
cfs_array
```

Output:

```
array([19.38470144, 16.57854845, 12.74433394,  7.87177728,  4.95049505])
```

Comment: this is still looping, right? i was hoping if there is any array-based method

Comment: @ian_chan Yes, it is loop-based - I don't of another way of doing it. Not sure what you mean by "array-based method".

Comment: i am not a python expert, so i dont know much about speed and efficiency etc. But what i had in mind was something like the reversed array of np.cumsum(cash_flow_array * discount_array), which I think it's prob do-able as i am typing this comment

Comment: i have edited the original post with what I have in mind based on our conversation